# Storing a temporary value of a constantly changing variable

Tags: java

I would like to know, is it possible to store a temporary value of a variable before it switches to another one?

Following is the code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int input = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        String input1 = String.valueOf(input);
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = input1.length() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            char charValueOfI = input1.charAt(i);
            String StringValueofI = String.valueOf(charValueOfI);
            int intValueofI = Integer.parseInt(StringValueofI);
            counter = 1;
    
            for (int j = intValueofI; j >0 ; j--) {
                counter = counter * j; // if input = 145, first value saved under counter will be 120, can that value of 120 be saved somewhere, before counter changes back to 1 under the first for loop

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The variable is _already_ assigned and "stored" before it changes. If you want to store it again somewhere else, use another variable. Please clarify what output you're expecting

Comment: Also, if I understand your code correctly, the first value of counter will be 5 since you're multiplying `1 * 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a sum variable before the for cycles, and in the first for, after the second, have the sum add the counter.

Answer (score 1):

> saved before counter changes back to 1

Sure. Put code before it resets that saves it. For example, a list

```
List<Integer> counters = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = input1.length() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        char charValueOfI = input1.charAt(i);
        String StringValueofI = String.valueOf(charValueOfI);
        int intValueofI = Integer.parseInt(StringValueofI);
        counter = 1;

        for (int j = intValueofI; j >0 ; j--) {
            counter = counter * j; 
        }
        counters.add(counter);
}
```